# Network scanning scope limited in Windows Server 2012

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012

**What I need ?:**
View all the computers of the network neighborhood (including all network segments, 192.168.1.x , 192.168.2.x , 192.168.3.x , etc)

**What is my problem ?:**
When I open network neighboorhood in windows server 2012 I can see computers in my network segment (192.168.1.x) but I can't see the rest of the computers in other segments ( 192.168.2.x , 192.168.3.x , etc)

**How is my Network ?:**
* We don't use Domain Controller
* We use a Mikrotik Router as the main router (each port manage 1 segment)
* We use nxfilter for internet surfing permits

**What I already did ?**
* use "add route" command with no success

Any idea ?, Thank you very much

Comment: Network browsing doesn't typically work across routers, because routers don't forward broadcast traffic, which is how most network browse lists are populated. If you really want to see the Windows computers on other networks you'll most likely need to deploy a WINS server and configure all of the Windows computers to use it.

Comment: WINS helps with cross-subnet name resolution, but it doesn't do anything for the browse lists (network neighborhood).   I do agree that WINS may be useful here though.

Answer (score 1):

First Network browsing is pretty much considered dead.  You really need to work on giving that up.  You also should strongly look at setting up a Domain, so you can have automatic Dynamic DNS registration.

If you don't have a domain, and you want the network neighborhood to actually work, you will need to setup a system that has a connection to each subnet, and will be configured to with the [Master Browser election](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959896.aspx).

Anyway I strongly suggest you read up on how [browsing works](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959912.aspx). (Yes, I know I am linking to Windows 2000 docs, this should be a hint to you that what you are asking is mostly dead.  Microsoft doesn't really have many updated docs on this topic).

As joeqwerty you can setup one or more systems as a [WINS server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736411.aspx), and configure your clients to use it (via DHCP).  Then systems will register their names on the WINS server.  This will not make populate the network neighborhood, but it will make name resolution for the computers work.

Comment: WINS will facilitate the population of the browse list (network neighborhood/my network places) across subnets. This is how we used WINS to facilitate such in networks/domains where we needed a browse list composed of Windows hosts from all subnets. - http://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2010/10/27/wins-what-is-it-how-to-install-it-and-how-to-configure-dhcp-scopes-for-wins-client-distribution/